# Last sent SMS/text message: how to retrieve via ContentObserver?

Tags: android, sms, contentobserver

I know that there are some questions around and I've been through them all, I guess.

My carrier is kind enough to offer 50 free SMS each month. Now I would like to make myself a little counter that runs in the background and notifies me whenever I reach that limit. (Yes, I *am* aware that there will already be apps for this). Therefore, I would like a service to be notified whenever an SMS/test msg is **sent**. So the way to go would be  a `ContentObserver`. I set one up (2) and register it like that (1):

```
(1)
Uri URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
String[] columns = {"_id", "date"};
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(URI, columns, "type=?", new String[]{"1"}, "_id DESC");
Observer observer = new Observer(context);
c.registerContentObserver(observer);

(2)
private class Observer extends ContentObserver {
    Context context;
    public Observer(Context context) {
        super(null);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        // some code here
    }
}
```

After countless attempts of messing I have to admit to myself I am plain unable to make the `onChange()` only go off when an SMS is sent. Instead, it goes off upon incoming SMS as well.

So can anyone help me out on this? Sure, I could write all outgoing SMS to a DB and query to find out if the current SMS already exists but that does seem like an untidy solution and I'd like to do differently.

Thanks in advance,
steff

Comment: @staff: "Therefore, I would like a service to be notified whenever an SMS/test msg is sent. So the way to go would be a ContentObserver." -- only for applications that use that content provider. Not all sent SMSes will be in that content provider, in large part because that content provider is not part of the operating system or SDK. For example, `SmsManager` does not record items in that content provider.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Marc, thank you for that hint, I am aware of that. But since there is now workaround and I only need that for a single, stock Nexus One this should work, right? I am not going to release it the public, it's just for me.

Comment: Other than figuring out how to better constrain your WHERE clause to only pick up sent items, I have no idea how to work around your problem. Sorry!

Comment: @CommonsWare Where does SmsManager log its messages?  How can you determine when it sends a message?

Comment: @gonzobrains: "Where does SmsManager log its messages?" -- it doesn't, any more than a socket logs every byte it sends. "How can you determine when it sends a message?" -- if you're the one sending the SMS, there are `PendingIntents` you can supply to determine disposition. If you are not the one sending the SMS, you have no way to know anything related to SMS is going on.