# how to i know in  my application, when i sent new message?

Tags: android

I am developing one application related to messages.

in my application i am getting all sent messages,by using contentresolver.

the code is

```
c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_sent,null, null, null, null);

        startManagingCursor(c);
if(c!=null)
       {

        ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout11)).setVisibility(View.GONE); 

         String columns ="body";
             String columns1 = "address";

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.main2,c, 
                    new String[] {columns1,columns},  new int[]{R.id.textView2, R.id.textView4}); 
                    ListView empListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                    empListView.setAdapter(adapter2);
}
```

it is working fine.

my requirement is when i am sending new message,

i want to hanlde  that in my application.

If any one know the solution,Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you may be talking about the broadcast receiver.

you can make broadcastreceiver for that purpose.

the broadcast about message is available in andorid os.

try search.

Comment: Bu using the brodcast resevers u will get information abour receive sms.but i want to know about sent sms.

Comment: sorry, I missunderstood. as I know there's no way to that. If you made an application that controlls sms. activity chooser will prompt to user which application to use. and user choosen your application, and user attempts to make new sms, your application will called.

Answer (score 0):

You can try registering a ContentObserver on the "content://sms/sent" ContentProvider, however it's not guaranteed that all SMS applications use that ContentProvider.

[Last sent SMS/text message: how to retrieve via ContentObserver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567003/last-sent-sms-text-message-how-to-retrieve-via-contentobserver)